# Get values form an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object:
(got the Content with this code:)

```
alert(JSON.stringify(objData));

{"food":[{"name":"Belgian Waffles","price":"$5.95","description":"Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup","calories":"650"},{"name":"Strawberry Belgian Waffles","price":"$7.95","description":"Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream","calories":"900"},{"name":"Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles","price":"$8.95","description":"Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream","calories":"900"},{"name":"French Toast","price":"$4.50","description":"Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread","calories":"600"},{"name":"Homestyle Breakfast","price":"$6.95","description":"Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns","calories":"950"}]}
```

I'm really new to JavaScript and want to get some values, for example all values of "Homestyle Breakfast" (last one)

```
thisResult = '';

        thisResult += 'Name: ' + objData.food.name;

        thisResult += '\nPrice: ' + objData.food.price;

        thisResult += '\nDescription: ' + objData.food.description;

        thisResult += '\nCalories: ' + objData.food.calories;

        alert(thisResult);
```

Why is that code not working?
I don't get anything with that code.

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (`food`) is an array so you should iterate it or you should know which key you need to display. For example is you want the last one you should change your `objData.food` with `objData.food[4]` or `objData.food[objData.food.length - 1]`

You can loop it with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objData.food.length; i++) {
    var food = objData.food[i];

    // for example display only that with name = Homestyle Breakfast
    if (food.name === 'Homestyle Breakfast') {
        thisResult = '';
        thisResult += 'Name: ' + food.name;
        thisResult += '\nPrice: ' + food.price;
        thisResult += '\nDescription: ' + food.description;
        thisResult += '\nCalories: ' + food.calories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your food is an array.

To fix this you can create a function that finds a food object that has a certain name and then return that object.

```js
var objData = {"food":[{"name":"Belgian Waffles","price":"$5.95","description":"Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup","calories":"650"},{"name":"Strawberry Belgian Waffles","price":"$7.95","description":"Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream","calories":"900"},{"name":"Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles","price":"$8.95","description":"Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream","calories":"900"},{"name":"French Toast","price":"$4.50","description":"Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread","calories":"600"},{"name":"Homestyle Breakfast","price":"$6.95","description":"Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns","calories":"950"}]};
var json = JSON.stringify(objData);

function getObjectByName(name){
    var food = {};
    for(var i=0; i< objData.food.length;i++){
        if(objData.food[i].name === name){
            food =  objData.food[i];
        }
    }
    return food;
}

var belgWaffle = getObjectByName('Belgian Waffles');
alert(belgWaffle.name+"\n"+belgWaffle.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `food` is an array you should access first the array by index to have access to the object in it:

```
thisResult = '';

thisResult += 'Name: ' + objData.food[0].name;

thisResult += '\nPrice: ' + objData.food[0].price;

thisResult += '\nDescription: ' + objData.food[0].description;

thisResult += '\nCalories: ' + objData.food[0].calories;
```

This can be the body of a loop s oyou build the string for each object in the array

Answer (score 0):

Because `food` is an array object and you want to treat like it:

```js
var objData = {
  "food": [{
    "name": "Belgian Waffles",
    "price": "$5.95",
    "description": "Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup",
    "calories": "650"
  }, {
    "name": "Strawberry Belgian Waffles",
    "price": "$7.95",
    "description": "Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream",
    "calories": "900"
  }, {
    "name": "Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles",
    "price": "$8.95",
    "description": "Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream",
    "calories": "900"
  }, {
    "name": "French Toast",
    "price": "$4.50",
    "description": "Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread",
    "calories": "600"
  }, {
    "name": "Homestyle Breakfast",
    "price": "$6.95",
    "description": "Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns",
    "calories": "950"
  }]
}


thisResult = '';

thisResult += 'Name: ' + objData.food[0].name;

thisResult += '\nPrice: ' + objData.food[0].price;

thisResult += '\nDescription: ' + objData.food[0].description;

thisResult += '\nCalories: ' + objData.food[0].calories;

alert(thisResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foodStore = {"food":[{"name":"Belgian Waffles","price":"$5.95","description":"Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup","calories":"650"},{"name":"Strawberry Belgian Waffles","price":"$7.95","description":"Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream","calories":"900"},{"name":"Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles","price":"$8.95","description":"Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream","calories":"900"},{"name":"French Toast","price":"$4.50","description":"Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread","calories":"600"},{"name":"Homestyle Breakfast","price":"$6.95","description":"Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns","calories":"950"}]}, // your object
    find = function find( type, field, value ) {
        return foodStore[type].filter(function (record) {
            if (record[field] === value) return true;
            return false;
        })[0];
    },
    mySearch = find('food', 'name', 'Homestyle Breakfast');
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach:

```js
var obj = { "food": [{ "name": "Belgian Waffles", "price": "$5.95", "description": "Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup", "calories": "650" }, { "name": "Strawberry Belgian Waffles", "price": "$7.95", "description": "Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream", "calories": "900" }, { "name": "Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles", "price": "$8.95", "description": "Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream", "calories": "900" }, { "name": "French Toast", "price": "$4.50", "description": "Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread", "calories": "600" }, { "name": "Homestyle Breakfast", "price": "$6.95", "description": "Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns", "calories": "950" }] };

function getFood(name) {
    var item;
    obj.food.some(function (a) {
        if (a.name === name) {
            item = a;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return item
}

function printFoodItem(item) {
    var cols = [{ name: 'Name' }, { price: 'Price' }, { description: 'Description' }, { calories: 'Calories' }];
    return cols.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var k = Object.keys(a);
        k in item && r.push(a[k] + ': ' + item[k]);
        return r;
    }, []).join('\n');
}

document.write('<pre>' + printFoodItem(getFood('French Toast')) + '</pre>');
```